# Maintaining backward compatibility in npm packages

Tags: angular, npm

I'm building an Angular npm package. I want to make sure that this package works with Angular 2, Angular 4 and Angular 5 applications. But I'm confused of how my approach of distributing this package should be. The following are my thoughts:

1. Should I maintain backward compatibility in each and every release of my package?
2. Or should I fix my package versions to a specific Angular version? For ex: myPackage@1.x for Angular 2, myPackage@2.x for Angular 4, myPackage@3.x for Angular 5? So that I can point the user to the right install command in the readme file of my npm package in case they need the package for older versions of Angular. Ex: If you want this package for Angular version 4 please npm install myPackage@2.0.5

I may sound silly as Im new in this area. But any help/pointers are highly appreciated.